# Move out files via rsync, but keep local copies for a while - how?

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I have a Linux server that periodically creates new data files I need elsewhere.

I need to **move** any new data files to another PC periodically, but also keep local copies of them for a limited amount of time (e. g. 7 days).

I can easily do the "moving away" part via `rsync`. But is there a reliable "standard" solution for creating and keeping local copies for up to a specific amount of time (and deleting older copies automatically), or do I have to write my own script for that?

Note that I need to create copies and not just keep the original files for a little longer (because otherwise, `rsync` would copy them again and again in case the files are gone from the remote PC for further processing).

Thanks!

Comment: there is no standard tool, why not create a `tmp7` directory somewhere and have `find tmp7 -mtime 7 -delete` run by crontab ? (this sounds like functionality from amazon's s3 storage)

Comment: `find` with `-mtime` seems simples. Have you thought about race conditions between `rsync`, the local copy and new file creation? Is there a time when no new files appear?

Comment: Thanks, deleting older files via find is what I was looking for. This would be done in the same script as rsync, so no race condition here.